# Como customizar o erro de falha de autenticação para retornar uma mensagem no Body da resposta?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth2

Quando ocorrer uma falha de autenticação no Spring Security, o mesmo retorna um erro no Header da resposta. Gostaria de customizar o erro e retornar uma mensagem no Body da resposta.

Abaixo está o código usado para validar o Oauth2 com o Spring Security Webflux com Opaque Token

```java
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque-token.introspection-uri}")
    private String introspectUri;
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque-token.client-id}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque-token.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/**").hasRole("read")
                .anyExchange().denyAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::opaqueToken);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveOpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector() {
        return new JwtOpaqueTokenIntrospector(this.introspectUri, this.clientId, this.clientSecret);
    }
}
```

**Response atual:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Response que desejo retornar**

```js
{
    "developerMessage": "Unauthorized - make sure the header parameter Authorization is valid",
    "userMessage": "You are not authorized to perform this operation",
    "errorCode": 30001,
    "moreInfo": ""
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow **in Portuguese**. As the name implies, the official language used here is Portuguese. So, can you please translate your question? If you prefer, you may also ask this same question in [the English StackOverflow site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais "Spring" de fazer isto é usar um `@RestControllerAdvice` para interceptar os erros e trocar a resposta do erro para o formato que desejar.

No caso do Spring, quando ele retornar o erro 401, provavelmente ele retornará a exceção `AccessDeniedException` para sinalizar isto. Sendo assim, você pode interceptar ela e trocar pela resposta que gostaria.

Seria algo assim:

```
@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandlerController {

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiErrorResponse> handleThrowable(AccessDeniedException ex, Locale locale) {
        log.error("Acesso não autorizado na API", ex);
        ApiErrorResponse error = new ApiErrorResponse("Unauthorized - make sure the header parameter Authorization is valid", "You are not authorized to perform this operation", 3001);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

}
```

A classe `ApiErrorResponse` é a classe com `developerMessage`, `userMessage`, `errorCode` e `moreInfo`.

Comment: com o webflux não consigo pegar a excessão desse jeito, ele não lança exceções. Estou chegando em uma solução aqui, depois vou postar como ficou. Tks

Comment: Blz. Tem algumas exceções do OAuth que não vão funcionar da maneira que coloquei acima, talvez seja isto. Veja esta minha resposta no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985310/customize-auth-error-from-spring-security-using-oauth2/55833524#55833524